# Why `var a = "..."` is faster than `var a = new String("...")`?

Tags: javascript, profiling

I'm trying to understand how Javascript works. Profiling some code, I've found that declarations in a "typed" oriented way are slower than declarations that not are "typed". Of course, I know that JS is not a typed language.

I've tested this on Firefox, Chrome and Opera, always with same results.

```js
var repetitions = 10000000;

console.time("a");
for (var i=0; i<repetitions; i++) {
    var a = "...";
}
console.timeEnd("a");

console.time("b");
for (var i=0; i<repetitions; i++) {
    var b = new String("...");
}
console.timeEnd("b")
```

Comment: This depends on the underlying engine implementation, which can be different for each browser/platform. What platforms have you tried? Have you compared this with other platforms? Can you say this phenomenon is universally true?

Comment: `toSource` is tagged as non-standard. Even though it shows what you state, there is no reason to believe, that the parser is doing the same steps for the two. Using `new` has more overhead than assigning a literal. However, there is no guarantee, that either will be faster/slower on some implementation. I don't see the merit in discussing this in great detail.

Comment: I've tested this on Firefox, Chrome and Opera, always with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V8 specifically, if you inspect the generated bytecode  (`node --print-bytecode`), you'll get something like this:

```
> return "..."

LdaConstant [0]
Return 

> return new String("...")

LdaGlobal [0], [0]
Star r0
LdaConstant [1]
Star r1
Ldar r0
Construct r0, r1-r1, [2]
Return
```

which basically means that a string literal just loads the pointer from the constants pool, while `new String` involves far more steps - load the global `String` object, load the constant, invoke the generic `Construct` method. I guess things are not much different in FF or any other engine.